# How to Change appbar Color on Scroll in material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change the background colour when I scroll down.
But don't know why it's not working.
My NavBar Component

```
import { useScrollTrigger } from "@mui/material";


const NavBar = (props) => {
  
 
  function ChangeColorOnScroll(props) {
    const { children, window } = props;
    const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
      disableHysteresis: true,
      threshold: 0,
      target: window ? window() : undefined,
    });

    return React.cloneElement(children, {
      style: { background: trigger ? "black" : "transparent" },
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ChangeColorOnScroll {...props}>
        <AppBar position="fixed" color="transparent">
         .....-> Component Data
        </AppBar>
      </ChangeColorOnScroll>
      <main>{props.children}</main>
    </>
  );
};
export default NavBar;
```

**Source code CodeSandbox**
*

> https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-boyd-njbx2u?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any `useScrollTrigger` hook implementation on your code but if you want to use it for changing the background color of the `AppBar` component when the page is scrolled, I give you a lot of examples of using the `useScrollTrigger` hooks here https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-usescrolltrigger-963ov.

One of them is changing the `AppBar` component background color when the page is scrolled.

The codesandbox above is created using Material UI v4 but is still relevant to MUI v5.